# invoking html elements dynamically in asp.net pages

Tags: html, asp.net

I am building a web page where I create divs based on data returned by SQL commands. I use literal then call sql command  reader.read and then a lot of loops to create my div I add all strings together all string += string of each loop
then use literal. It works is it a bad practice ? What do you think and why it is bad/good?

Comment: This question is a bit generic for this site, but it sounds like a terrible idea and totally not how asp.net is supposed to work.

Comment: enlighten me then, that's why I am asking

Comment: If you're using asp.net, you should be using either web forms or MVC design pattern to display data in the page based on what you have in your database that you want to display. There are thousands of articles and tutorials online, so I am uncertain how better to answer you other than to point you to one of those. If there is a reason you chose the design that you chose, please let us know.

Comment: It does the job and it is easier than other methods, I am using web forms, in the back-end I am fetching data on load and then creating the divs on load also, I saw a lot of tutorials and this method was not one of them but it was the easier for me to use as I come from winform background and this is my first web application

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, because everytime you concatenate a string you are making a new instance with the content of the concatenated string and this could be very expensive for your server, depending on the amount of concatenations you make. Instead of using `string += string`, I would use a StringBuilder and the return at the final the content of this StringBuilder.

```
     public static void Main()
     {
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          for (int i= 0; i <= 10; i++) {
             sb.Append("<div>");
             sb.Append("your content goes here");
             sb.Append("</div>");
          }   
          Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

       }
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and I will note that, but actually my main question is about using literal. is it the right way to add html elements to the page based on result  ?

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your code? I don't know what you mean with literal.